# js object with logged in state vs just server-side session

Tags: php, javascript, session, session-cookies, session-state

Is it common to have a js object with duplicate data from the server's session?

For example, if a user is logged in, I store this server side in my `$_SESSION`. But when I'm in the client, I can't check logged in state without checking some part of the DOM (which is bad), or sending some Ajax call to check the value in `$_SESSION`. Should I just create a js object that holds duplicate data?

Seems like a bad idea since now I will always need to keep two objects in sync, but I'm not sure how else to solve this.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here?
A little infobox where a user can see if he's logged in?

Comment: I see no problem in having them in sync

Comment: If you really need the value client-side, then yes, it's common to keep them in sync.

Comment: @cIph3r - for example when you click upvote on StackOverflow, how does it know whether you are logged in or not? I'm assuming it has a js object that it can check. Or a cookie? I'm not sure how this should be done.

Comment: If you are logged in, you can check this on serverside,
then generate a response `if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) echo "loggedin" else echo "loggedout"`.


I see no problem here.
The only problem might be, if your session is timedout. But this can be checked by polling or ignored because it is rather an unisual case.

Answer (score 0):

You could echo a few lines of Javascript into the browser as it loads, or have a separate script that is pulled when $_SESSION variables are needed. So, you could have a file, "session.php" that contains only the lines:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

Then you could use it in your Javascript/HTML (so that you don't have to do fancy AJAX or anything):

```
var session = <?php include('session.php'); ?>
```

I've built a live example here: http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14919887/
With the code available for download here: http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14919887/code.zip

Keep in mind that you'll need to keep them in sync, if you want them to change between loadings of the page, you'll have to look into AJAX, and json_decode.